# Critical Points of smooth map on a compact manifold

Tags: solution-verification, smooth-manifolds

**PROBLEM**

Show that a smooth map $f$ from compact manifold $N$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ has a critical point.

**HINT**

Let $(U, \phi)$ a chart about $p \in N$ and $\pi: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ the projection on the first factor. Let $A \subset U$ a closed subset, $N$ is a compact manifold, then $A$ is compact.
We know that $\phi : U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a diffeomorphism, then $\phi(A)$ is compact subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The function
$$
\pi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1} : \phi(A) \to \mathbb{R}
$$
is a smooth function (Because is a composition of smooth functions). As $\phi(A)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. By Weistrass theorem (or Extreme value theorem) a function deffined on a compact set, $\pi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ has a critical point $\phi(q) \in \phi(A)$. Hence, $(\pi\circ f \circ \phi^{-1})(\phi(q))$ is a critical value for $\pi\circ f$.

Is my proof correct so far? How should I complete the proof?

Comment: So far you've shown that $q$ is a critical point of $\pi \circ f$. In fact, you can conclude that $d(\pi \circ f)(q) = 0$ because the derivative must vanish at an interior maximum. From here the proof can be completed.

Comment: Thanks!!! I managed to finish. From there, I was able to show that $f$ is not submersion at $p$ and therefore $p$ is a critical point.

Comment: @HornedSphere There is a typo in your question. The result isn't true if the codomain is $\Bbb R^m$: it has to be $\Bbb R$ instead. Counter-example: the inclusion map $S^{n}\to \Bbb R^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to involve charts.

Let $\def\RR{\mathbb R}f:M\to\RR$ be a smooth function on a compact manifold. Since $f$ is continuous, there is a point $p$ in $M$ such that $f(p)\leq f(q)$ for all $q\in M$. Let $X$ be vector tangent to $M$ at $p$, so that there is a smooth function $\alpha:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to M$ such that $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha'(0)=X$. The function $f\circ \alpha:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to\RR$ is smooth and clearly has an absolute minimum at $0$, so its derivative at $0$ is $0$. The chain rule tells us that $$0=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\Bigr|_{t=0}(f\circ\alpha)(t)=Xf=df(X).$$ We thus see that the linear map $df:T_pM\to\RR$ is zero, that is, that $p$ is a critical point of $f$.